# nginx configuration does not start

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to setup NGINX server as benchmark to test client-server interaction. The root in the server contains a few thousand random html pages.

This is also my first work with applications like NGINX. I have been struggling to configure nginx for awhile now using this website [1] and the documentation of nginx.

To give you some more background, I setup nginx on my local machine and the installation on a specific-directory (called libs, bad naming -- I should change that.)

After starting nginx using `./sbin/nginx -c conf/nginx.conf` I tried to curl on the website to check if it is functional 
`curl http://127.0.0.1:6011`

And I get this error:

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.15.10</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Where am I going wrong in my configuration?

[1] https://www.slashroot.in/nginx-web-server-performance-tuning-how-to-do-it

```
worker_processes  32;
worker_rlimit_nofile 51200;
error_log  /lustre1/nginx-benchmark/libs/logs/error.log;
error_log  /lustre1/nginx-benchmark/libs/logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  /lustre1/nginx-benchmark/libs/logs/error.log  info;
pid        /lustre1/nginx-benchmark/libs/logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  50000;
    multi_accept on;
}


http {
    include       /lustre1/nginx-benchmark/libs/conf/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    #gzip  on;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /lustre1/nginx-benchmark/libs/logs/access.log  main;


    server {
        listen 6011 default_server;
        listen [::]:6011 default_server ipv6only=on;
        server_name  localhost;
        #listen       6011;
        #server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        access_log  /lustre1/nginx-benchmark/libs/logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /lustre1/nginx-benchmark/dataset/1024/;
            try_files $uri html/index.html;
#index.php;
            index  index.html index.htm;

        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /lustre1/nginx-benchmark/libs/html/50x.html {
            root   /lustre1/nginx-benchmark/libs/html;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: What is your root directory? the one where the index.html located?

Comment: You don't have any definition of `root` before `location /` so what does the directory `/` means?

Comment: /lustre1/nginx-benchmark/libs/html --> that's where index.html and 50x.html are present.

`/lustre1/nginx-benchmark/dataset/1024` -> that's where the data is present

Comment: In order for the nginx to be able to serve the index.html, try to add `root /lustre1/nginx-benchmark/libs/html;` BEFORE the location directive, and change the location directive as `location / { try_files $uri $uri/ index.html};`.

Comment: OK, but where would the dataset/1024 go? and can you provide you above example as the answer?

Comment: BTW, how many CPU cores your server have that you set `worker_processes` to `32`, it is general set to match the number of CPU cores or to `auto` (i.e. let the nginx to decide).

Comment: What I'm suggesting is fixing the 404 that you are facing. It does not solve on how to read the data from dataset/1024 directory. I assumed that you have backend app or html file that will read the data from the dataset/1024 directory, but you didn't mentioned what backend you are using and there is no backend configuration in your settings, so I don't know how you read the data from dataset, without that I can't comment on that.

Comment: The backend basically requests for fixed number of pages at a time (https://github.com/giltene/wrk2)

Comment: BTW, how many CPU cores that you nginx server have that you set `worker_process` to 32? General it is set to match number of CPU cores or to `auto` to let nginx server to decide (which will be based on number of cpu cores). `worker_connections  50000;` is also a lot unless you are expecting huge traffic from day 1.

Comment: This is a simulated environment to test `high throughput` environments. so, we set the worker connections to 500k.
The machine is a `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2695 `

Comment: I think you should really to get better understanding on how nginx works, generally html are static content that should be cached and handled by the nginx and only pass the dynamic requests to the backend server (running c or python or whatever web frameworks). Furthermore, if you are expecting the simulated traffic, you probably need to have a load-balancer before a multiple nginx servers....

Comment: agreed. i'll spend a few more days..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you `ls` any files in `/lustre1/nginx-benchmark/dataset/1024/`?

```
ls -l /lustre1/nginx-benchmark/dataset/1024/
```

If you can't then, that's why nginx is 404ing your request - it can't see them either. If you can, what are the permissions on that folder and the files? Are they readable by the user nginx is running as? What about the parent folders of that path?

Add an error log with debug, to see what nginx thinks the problem is:

```
 access_log /lustre1/nginx-benchmark/libs/logs/host.access.log main;
 error_log /lustre1/nginx-benchmark/libs/logs/host.error.log debug;
```

Change your `try_files` line to look like this:

```
try_files $uri /index.html =404;
```

The `=404` should terminate nginx's repeated checking, which is probably being caused by your `/lustre1/nginx-benchmark/dataset/1024/` docroot not having a `html/index.html` in it.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to `ls -l` in to the directory `dataset/1024`.  The permission to the folder are prematurely set as `chmod -R +777 dataset/` (`drwxrwxrwx`)

The host.error.log gives the following error `1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:6011"` With the curl giving a `internal server error now`.

Comment: Edited my answer for a suggested change to your `try_files` line

Comment: still the same issue. I'll check abit more and jump back here

Comment: your original `try_files` had `html/index.html` - does your `/lustre1/nginx-benchmark/dataset/1024/` docroot have an `html` folder inside it?

Comment: It does not. it only have a bunch of 1kb html files named, 1.html, 2.html so on

Comment: When you changed the `try_files` line with my `=404` suggestion, did you also change your `html/index.html` to `/index.html`?

Comment: If you only have `1.html`, `2.html` etc do you actually have an `index.html` at all?

Comment: Your point stands good. Pushing a copy of the index.html to dataset/1024 fixed the issue. but, now this error raises:
`*45987 writev() failed (32: Broken pipe), client: localhost, server: localhost, request: "GET /119.html HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:6011"`

Comment: Do you actually get the contents of 119.html back from curl when you call `http://127.0.0.1:6011/119.html`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191266/discussion-between-tandem-and-jaygooby).